# how to find printer list with thw help of javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find all printers which are accessible from my PC with the help of JavaScript. Any help is welcome; since I have already spent a lot of time; yet I am far from finding a proper solution.

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: grammar improvement.

Comment: You don't have access to that kind of information in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using node.js assuming you are running Windows.
I used the package [node-powershell](http://rannn505.github.io/node-powershell/). If you aren't on Windows, you can probably use `child_process.exec` and run the mac equivalent of this Powershell command.

The powershell command

```
get-WmiObject -class Win32_printer | ft name, systemName, shareName
```

will list all printers connected to the computer.

After installing node-powershell, the following Javascript will list all printers connected to the computer.

```
'use strict';

// get-WmiObject -class Win32_printer | ft name, systemName, shareName

var shell = require('node-powershell');

var ps = new shell({
  executionPolicy: 'Bypass',
  noProfile: true
});

ps.addCommand(' get-WmiObject -class Win32_printer | ft name, systemName, shareName');
ps.invoke().then(function (output) {
  console.log(output);
}).catch(function (err) {
  console.log(err);
  ps.dispose();
});
```

Output from my test run (I'm on Windows 10 with Node 6.10)

```
>node list_printers.js
NPS>  Process 100328 started

NPS>  Command invoke started
NPS>   get-WmiObject -class Win32_printer | ft name, systemName, shareName
NPS>  Command invoke finished


name                                     systemName   shareName
----                                     ----------   ---------
Send To OneNote 2016                     THINKPAD-P50
Quicken PDF Printer                      THINKPAD-P50
Microsoft XPS Document Writer            THINKPAD-P50
Microsoft Print to PDF                   THINKPAD-P50
HP Officejet 5740 series                 THINKPAD-P50
Foxit Reader PDF Printer                 THINKPAD-P50
Fax - HP Officejet 5740 series (Network) THINKPAD-P50
Fax                                      THINKPAD-P50
Brother MFC-9330CDW Printer              THINKPAD-P50
```